# Is this use of 把 and 过 correct?

Tags: grammar, simplified-characters

Ｉ read that you should not use a 把 construction with 过 as an aspect particle for the verb. But I came across this sentence:

他把手机摔坏过两三次

Is this correct ?

Answer (score 1):

> 他把手机摔坏过两三次

It's correct. 过 here denotes **the action has happened**. The action is 摔坏. The sentence can be parsed as:

> [他] [把(手机)摔坏过] [两三次]

In English: *he has dropped and crashed his phone a couple of times*.

Comment: problem: find more examples on the web of 把 + object + verb + aspect particle 过；there seems to be an unlimited number of 把 + object + verb + aspect particle 了，and a much smaller number with 着, also combination 着了:
 他又把门开着了